# How can I find visited nodes called in functions?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

Here's my programme of Binary Search Tree, all the functions are working in uploading system, except the last one, I somehow have to find out which of the Nodes I visited throughout calling previous functions. Any ideas?

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = value

    class BinarySearchTree:
        def __init__(self):
            self.root = None

        def insert(self, value):
            if self.root is None:
                self.root = Node(value)
            else:
                self._insert(value, self.root)

        def _insert(self, value, curNode):
            if value < curNode.data:
                if curNode.left is None:
                    curNode.left = Node(value)
                else:
                    self._insert(value, curNode.left)
            else:
                if curNode.right is None:
                    curNode.right = Node(value)
                else:
                    self._insert(value, curNode.right)

        def fromArray(self, array):
            for i in range(len(array)-1):
                value = array[i]
                self.insert(value)
                i += 1


        def search(self, value):
            if self.root is not None:
                return self._search(value, self.root)
            else:
                return False

        def _search(self, value, curNode):
            if value == curNode.data:
                return True
            elif value < curNode.data and curNode.left is not None:
                self._search(value, curNode.left)
            elif value > curNode.data and curNode.right is not None:
                self._search(value, curNode.right)
            else:
                return False

        def min(self):
            curNode = self.root
            while curNode.left is not None:
                curNode = curNode.left
            return curNode

        def max(self):
            curNode = self.root
            while curNode.right is not None:
                curNode = curNode.right
            return curNode

        def visitedNodes(self):
            pass
```

And it has to return the values of nodes in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight forward answer would be to add a `visited` flag to each node, that is explicitly flipped in each of your functions when a `Node` is visited:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = value
        self.visited = False
```

and then:

```
def _search(self, value, curNode):
    curNode.visited = True
    if value == curNode.data:
        return True
    # etc., unchanged
```

Same for `min` and `max`, and finally:

```
def visitedNodes(self, current=self.root, accumulator=[]):
    if current == None:
        return
    if current == self.root:
        accumulator = []
    if current.visited:
        accumulator.append(current)
    visitedNodes(current.left)
    visitedNodes(current.right)
    return accumulator
```

This is just one implementation, there are many other ways to do this. I also assume this function, which traverses the whole tree, should **not** set the `visited` flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify your current code, maybe this can help you:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self._data = value
        self.visited = False
    @property
    def data(self):
        self.visited = True
        return self._data
    @data.setter
    def data(self, value):
        self.visited = False
        self._data = value
n = Node(3)
print(n.visited)
print(n.data)
print(n.visited)
```

Output:

```
False
3
True
```

Then in your `visitedNodes` method you would have to look at the visited attribute of everynode. (Which will be slow)

Other way of doing it is adding a new `set` attribute to your BinarySearchTree and manually `add` a node each time you look at it, this will make you modify your code.

Comment: This is a little bit comlicated for me, but I'd like to know how could I count the number of visited nodes?

Comment: @AlessandroPetric it is not complicated at all, it does the same that Arne told you to do, with the exception that this Node class automatically sets visited to true when you lookup the data "attribute" and sets it to false when you set the data attribute. So you dont have to worry about when to set visited to true. Each time you visit (i.e. use the data of the node) it will set its own visited attribute to True.